# a script for installing node, npm and mongodb across all platforms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I have a `nodejs` web application that also requires `mongodb`.

And i want to create a zip of source codes and `package.json`. That should be shipped to a person.

The person may take that zip to any operating system.
The person need to extract the zip file, switch to (terminal/command line), move into extracted directory, then do npm install and then start the web app using `node index.js`.

In these whole procedure, (i assume the person have suitable extractor tool respective of his os), the person only need `node`, `npm` and `mongodb`.

I am looking for just two scripts (only one for ALL *nix based system and only one for ALL windows based systems), that would gracefully check and then install (if not already installed) the above three entities.

EDIT : i am looking for an alternative of `docker`. Because i guess docker would need very large shipment file, And probably also requires a little high configuration server. which i do not want.

Comment: This sounds like a good use-case for [docker](https://docker.com) although I'm not entirely sure about the status of their Windows support.

Comment: Contrary to what you think docker is exactly the solution you need. Configuration of the server might be necessary, but it depends

Comment: Docker does not need a large shipment file as you could build your container from the source on the machine. I can't think of a better tool for your usecase